# append list 1 in list 2 ..I want to have a output like this [1, 2], [3, 4]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[3,4]
list1.append(list2)
print(list1)
```

I want to have an output like this `[1, 2], [3, 4]` but it is giving the output like this `[1, 2, [3, 4]]`. What is going wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want `list1, list2 = [1, 2], [3, 4]` as the result, just remove the `list1.append(list2)` line and you're done. Are you trying to construct a list like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`?

Comment: sorry I want to have the output like this [1, 2], [3, 4] .. but I want to use append function to do this as it's the requirement of my assignment

Comment: `[1, 2], [3, 4]` would be a tuple with two lists inside, but you can't `append` to a tuple, so I'm still not sure what you want. Maybe you're saying you want to _print_ the result like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want list1 = [[1,2], [3,4]]

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[3,4]
list1 = [list1, list2]
print(list1)
```

If you want list1 = [[1,2], [3,4]], using append (requested in comments).

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[3,4]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1)
list3.append(list2)
print(list3)
```

Comment: I want to use the append function to add list 2 in list 1 so that the output will be like this [1, 2], [3, 4]

Comment: @ShahzadKhan That statement is contradictory. Use the tool that gives you the desired output, but `append` is not that tool.